# Using a compiled function inside NIntegrate gives "CompiledFunction::cfsa" message

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, compile

The following function is defined for `Real` input:

```
FFc = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {EF, _Real}},If[x > EF, 0., If[x == EF, 0.5, 1.]]]
```

`FFc` is now used in the function called `foo`:

```
EBoundary = 6.5;
foo[Ef_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[FFc[x, Ef] , {x, -EBoundary, EBoundary}]
```

When I call `foo` like

```
foo[3.2]
```

I get an error message:

```
CompiledFunction::cfsa: "Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.
```

Since I'm using real numbers I have no idea why I get this message. What is the problem? Is it because `If[]` can return `0`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's because `FFc` is being passed `x` and `Ef` symbolically, at first. To cure the problem, add an intermediate function between `FFc` and `NIntegrate`, such as

```
f[x_?NumericQ, Ef_?NumericQ] := FFc[x,Ef]
```

then

```
foo[Ef_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, Ef] , {x, -EBoundary, EBoundary}]
```

Comment: Do you perhaps know why adding `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}` to `FFc` does not cure the problem?

Comment: @Ajasja Seems related to why `FFc[-x,0.]` gives error while `FFc[x,0.]` doesn't. I wonder why `NIntegrate` passes `-x` as argument to the function. (This comment is assuming `{"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`)

Comment: @Ajasja Seems if the integration region is `{x,-a,a}` it doesn't work, while it is unsymmetric like `{x,-a-0.00001,a}` it does

Comment: @Ajasja no idea. `Compile` is not my strong suit.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps @OleksandR will see this:)

Comment: A same trick has been applied in this question, too.  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/40755/5943

Comment: I am worried that this solution might affect the performance boost that `Compile` is supposed to give. I am referring to the `_?NumericQ` pattern matching. Isn't there a more direct solution? Perhaps in Math 10?

Comment: @becko have you tried it with and without `NumericQ`? That is the only way to tell definitively. But, I suspect the speed hit will be marginal.

Comment: What effect does the introduction of an interim function have on performance?  Is there another solution?

Comment: @DougKimzey honestly, I don't know if it has much effect on performance, but relative to `NIntegrate`, I don't expect it to be very large. That said, you can [turn off](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111440/52) symbolic processing in `NIntegrate` by setting `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`.

Answer (score 11):

This answer addresses [Ajasja's question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17993#comment54465_17994) in rcollyer's answer:

> Do you perhaps know why adding `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}` to `FFc` does not cure the problem?

This is due to the fact that the methods inside `NIntegrate[]` (attempt to) perform a preliminary symbolic analysis, which can be helpful for integrands composed of built-in mathematical functions, but not terribly useful for compiled functions. Thus, one has to turn it off in this case, in addition to enabling the compilation options mentioned by Ajasja.

Here is a quick demonstration:

```
FFc = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {EF, _Real}}, 
              If[x > EF, 0., If[x == EF, 0.5, 1.]], 
              "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}];
```

With the default setting, we get this (*Mathematica* 10.4):

```
NIntegrate[FFc[x, 3.2], {x, -6.5, 6.5}]
```

> ```
> CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument -x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.
> CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument -x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number.
> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the
> following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or
> WorkingPrecision too small.
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9
> recursive bisections in x near {x} = {3.22441}. NIntegrate obtained 9.699759342263453`
> and 0.0005405922634428764` for the integral and error estimates.
> ```

before `9.69976` is returned. In contrast, if we disable symbolic processing like so:

```
NIntegrate[FFc[x, 3.2], {x, -6.5, 6.5}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
```

> ```
> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the
> following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or
> WorkingPrecision too small.
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 9
> recursive bisections in x near {x} = {3.22441}. NIntegrate obtained 9.699759342263453`
> and 0.0005405922634428764` for the integral and error estimates.
> ```

we no longer get the `CompiledFunction::cfsa` message.

Comment: Nice find and explanation.

Comment: @rcollyer, I think this was asked during one of my hiatuses, so I had missed it until Jason linked to it in another question. :)

Comment: For some reason it does not work in M11.1 or 11.2

Comment: Using  `f1p11 = Compile[{{p, _Real, 1}, {pq, _Real, 1}, {pqq, _Real, 1}}, 
  E^-(#.# &[p + pq/2 - pqq/2]), CompilationTarget -> "C", 
  RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed", "EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}]` and `NIntegrate[
 f1p11[{px, py}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}], {px, py} \[Element] 
  BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[Disk[{1, 1}/2 - {2, 2}/2, 3]], 
 Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0, 
   Method -> {"MonteCarloRule", "Points" -> 500}}, PrecisionGoal -> 3]` <br/> I get `CompiledFunction::cfta: Argument {px,py}...`

Comment: @luu, I don't have a C compiler to verify your observations; 2. IIRC special handling is done for geometric integrals (i.e. those involving regions). This answer is mostly intended to explain the univariate case. Consider asking [a new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) if this is still troubling you.

Comment: Sometimes life can be so easy, thank you for this comment. I also stumbled over this tiny little problem.