# Why Min cannot be used as constrains of NMinimize?

Tags: broken-code, precedence

I met a strange problem when trying to do an optimization.

Initialization code,

```
goal = 2.;
vector = {1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5};

f[m1_Real, m2_Real] := Block[{v},
   v = Map[# + m1*Sin[Norm[{m1, m2}]] &, vector];
   Clip[v, {0, goal}]];

g[m1_Real, m2_Real] := Max[(goal - f[m1, m2])/goal] + Norm[{m1, m2}];
```

where `f` is a vector function and `g` is a scaler function. I want to minimize `g[m1,m2]` with constrains `0.8 <= Min[f[m1,m2]] <= 1.0` and `0 <= m1 <= 2 && 0 <= m2 <=2`. Despite this seems straightforward, a direct implementation is problematic,

```
counter = 0;
NMinimize[{
  g[m1, m2],
  And[0.8 <= Min[f[m1, m2]]/goal <= 1.0, 0 <= m1 <= 2, 0 <= m2 <= 2]
  }, {m1, m2},
  Method -> {"NelderMead", "Tolerance" -> .001},
  StepMonitor :> (Print[++counter, ":\t", {m1, m2}])]
```

If we execute the code, an error message NMinimize::bcons will be shown, which tells us that the constrains are not in the valid format.

After a few tests I found out that the the problem is related to the command `Min` used in the first constrain `0.8 <= Min[f[m1, m2]]/goal <= 1.0`. If we do not use `Min` then there will be no problem, i.e., `0.8 <= Evaluate[Norm[f[m1, m2]/goal]] <= 1.0` can be evaluated without any problem.

So it seems that `Min` is not valid for using as constrains with `NMizimize` (yet we can use `Norm`, `Plus`, etc.). But this is really inconvenient because I do need to use `Min` as part of the constrains. I wonder if we can fix this problem?

Comment: Since the first entry in the function result is always the minimum, why not just use it?

Comment: @rasher, the math used in this code is just an easy example, my real problem is much more complex than it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve your problem, let's first take a good look at the warning generated by your code:

> ```
> NMinimize::bcons: The following constraints are not valid:
> {0 <= m1, 0 <= m2, 0.8 <= 0.5 f[m1, m2], m1 <= 2, m2 <= 2, 0.5 f[m1, m2] <= 1.}.
> Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain
> specifications involving the variables. >>
> ```

What have you found? Our constraints are not valid, yeah, we know that, but what else? Oh, we see the constraints have been displayed by *Mathematica* and the form of them have been slightly changed, um, that's understandable, and we can easily find the correspondence between them and their original, `0 <= m1` and `0 <= m2` and `m1 <= 2` and `m2 <= 2` are for `0 <= m1 <= 2` and `0 <= m2 <= 2`, `0.8 <= 0.5 f[m1, m2]` and `0.5 f[m1, m2] <= 1.` are…… wait, where's the `Min`? Where did it go? *Mathematica* don't like it so she deleted it?

Of course not, `Min` disappeared because it has been calculated before `f[m1, m2]` become number lists. What happened here is just same as:

```
Clear[m1, m2]
Min@f[m1, m2]
```

> ```
> f[m1, m2]
> ```

This can be approved by `Trace`:

```
NMinimize[{g[m1, m2], 
           And[0.8 <= Min@f[m1, m2]/goal <= 1.0, 0 <= m1 <= 2, 0 <= m2 <= 2]}, 
          {m1, m2}, 
          Method -> {"NelderMead", "Tolerance" -> .001}] // Trace
```

> ```
> {{{0.8 <= Min[f[m1, m2]]/goal <= 1. && 0 <= m1 <= 2 && 
>    0 <= m2 <= 2, {{{Min[f[m1, m2]], f[m1, m2]}…………
> ```

To fix your code, you can definite a new function that calculates only if its argument is a list:

```
min[x_List] := Min[x]

counter = 0;
(* I removed your Method option since it seems to be unnecessary. *)
NMinimize[{g[m1, m2], 
           And[0.8 <= min@f[m1, m2]/goal <= 1.0, 0 <= m1 <= 2, 0 <= m2 <= 2]}, 
          {m1, m2},  
          StepMonitor :> (Print[++counter, ":\t", {m1, m2}])]
```

> ```
>  {1.02036, {m1 -> 0.820357, m2 -> 2.34313*10^-8}}
> ```

Comment: @rasher Frankly speaking, warnings of _Mathematica_ are usually discouraging at first sight, but it's really helpful for debugging if we read carefully.

Comment: @xzczd, Your definition of `min[x_List]` subtly postpones the evaluation of `min@f[m1, m2]` until the desired state is reached. This is a very nice trick. I was thinking something like to use `Hold` and `ReleaseHold` to do the same, but faild to find a way to actually *insert* these command inside `NMinimize`... Thank you for your answer! And you have my gratitude for showing the subtle trick.