# Using compiled function inside NMinimize

Tags: mathematical-optimization, compile

Consider this code:

```
variable = Sin[x];
fun = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, variable, CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
NMinimize[fun[x], {x}]
```

This code returns:

```
 CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>
 {-1., {x -> -1.5707963267948966}}
```

Why do I get the error? How can I resolve this issue?

Edit

What if we use instead of Sin an expression like a+b? Because in reality I have an expression with 63 variable which must be find by NMinimize I cannot define a function of that expression and use it instead of Sin

Comment: I cannot reproduce  this pb on mma 9 macos. try x=. first?

Comment: minimizing a function of 63 variable can be a bit challenging :-)

Comment: @chris I already did it but it takes two hours to get the results. I thought if I compile the function which I want to minimize I may get some speed up. In another case, I realized that the compiled function is fast at least 3 times than when I use pure functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update

> What if we use instead of Sin an expression like a+b?

I'll try a simple example, namely minimizing $(a + 3)^2 + (b - 3)^2$. Making use of [`CompilationOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CompilationOptions.html), I'll define a function with two variables, then nest that inside another compiled function prior to minimization.

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]

myfunction = Compile[{{a}, {b}}, (a + 3)^2 + (b - 3)^2]

With[{variable = myfunction},
  fun = Compile[{{a, _Real}, {b, _Real}},
    variable[a, b],
    "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
    CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True},
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]
  ];

NMinimize[fun[x, y], {x, y}]

(* {1.97215*10^-30, {x -> -3., y -> 3.}} *)
```

You can add `// Trace` to the `NMinimize` to check for errors. For example, if you remove the line `"RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}`, adding `// Trace` throws up the `cfsa` error from before.

And again, let's check all is well with the compilation.

```
CompilePrint[fun]

(*
    2 arguments
    5 Real registers
    Underflow checking off
    Overflow checking off
    Integer overflow checking on
    RuntimeAttributes -> {}

    R0 = A1
    R1 = A2
    Result = R4

    1   R2 = R0
    2   R3 = R1
    3   R4 = R2 + R3
    4   Return
*)
```

No calls to `MainEvaluate`.

### Original answer

This works for me.

```
With[{variable = Sin}, 
  fun = Compile[{{a, _Real}}, variable[a], 
    "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}]
  ];
NMinimize[fun[x], x]
```

And let's check all is well:

```
Needs["CompiledFunctionTools`"]
With[{variable = Sin}, 
  fun = Compile[{{a, _Real}}, variable[a], 
    "RuntimeOptions" -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False}, 
    CompilationTarget -> "C"]
  ];
CompilePrint[fun]

(*
        1 argument
        2 Real registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking on
        RuntimeAttributes -> {}

        R0 = A1
        Result = R1

        1   R1 = Sin[ R0]
        2   Return
*)
```

As to *why* you get this problem, this question should answer it for you: [Using a compiled function inside NIntegrate gives "CompiledFunction::cfsa" message](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17993/using-a-compiled-function-inside-nintegrate-gives-compiledfunctioncfsa-messa)

Comment: What if we use instead of `Sin` an expression like `a+b`?
Because in reality I have an expression with 63 variable which must be find by NMinimize I cannot define a function of that expression and use it instead of `Sin`.

Comment: Does my edit answer your question?

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you. Although I have to install C compiler to use the `CompilationTarget`.

Comment: Sorry yes, though the Windows SDK should be straightforward enough to download.

Comment: I am in need of the similar thing (hopefully) to speed up my optimization. I might be wrong. But did you compile the function twice? (very top example of your post) First compile the function `myfunction`, then `fun` again.

Comment: I did, and `CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}` ensures it the first function is defined in the second.

Answer (score 2):

In principle 63 variable is not a problem.

Lets define them

```
var = Table[ToExpression["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 64}];
```

and  a Quadratic function

```
Q = var.var;
```

This defines the function

```
fun = 
  Compile[Sequence@Map[{{#, _Real}} &, var] // Evaluate, Q, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];
```

and the minimization proceeds as it should

```
NMinimize[fun @@ var, var]

(*
==> {0., {x1 -> 0., x2 -> 0., x3 -> 0., x4 -> 0., x5 -> 0., 
  x6 -> 0., x7 -> 0., x8 -> 0., x9 -> 0., x10 -> 0., x11 -> 0., 
  x12 -> 0., x13 -> 0., x14 -> 0., x15 -> 0., x16 -> 0., x17 -> 0., 
  x18 -> 0., x19 -> 0., x20 -> 0., x21 -> 0., x22 -> 0., x23 -> 0., 
  x24 -> 0., x25 -> 0., x26 -> 0., x27 -> 0., x28 -> 0., x29 -> 0., 
  x30 -> 0., x31 -> 0., x32 -> 0., x33 -> 0., x34 -> 0., x35 -> 0., 
  x36 -> 0., x37 -> 0., x38 -> 0., x39 -> 0., x40 -> 0., x41 -> 0., 
  x42 -> 0., x43 -> 0., x44 -> 0., x45 -> 0., x46 -> 0., x47 -> 0., 
  x48 -> 0., x49 -> 0., x50 -> 0., x51 -> 0., x52 -> 0., x53 -> 0., 
  x54 -> 0., x55 -> 0., x56 -> 0., x57 -> 0., x58 -> 0., x59 -> 0., 
  x60 -> 0., x61 -> 0., x62 -> 0., x63 -> 0., x64 -> 0.}}
*)
```

It works more generally for another objective function

```
 Q = (var - Table[i, {i, 64}]) //(#.# + (#.#)^2) &;
fun = Compile[Sequence@Map[{{#, _Real}} &, var] // Evaluate, Q, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}];   
NMinimize[fun @@ var, var];//Timing
```

(* ===> 0.78 sec. *)

Comment: I got this error, although it returns the answer:

CompiledFunction::cfsa: Argument x1 at position 1 should be a machine-size real number. >>

Comment: There's not much point in compiling this though, because when you check `CompilePrint[fun]` it has lots of calls to `MainEvaluate`? Indeed, if I just run `NMinimize[Q, var] // AbsoluteTiming` it takes 0.35 seconds and returns the correct answer with no errors.

Comment: sure but the OP wanted to demonstrate that the pb came from compilation over 63 variables.

Comment: Yep fair point!