# How to programmatically construct a function or a compiled function?

Tags: function-construction, compile, functional-style, hold

I'd like to programmatically construct a function from a long expression with many duplicate terms.  The objective is to programmatically create a set of compiled functions with expressions that were previously created programmatically.  This is somewhat related to [Stack Exchange Question: How to speed up an optimization with very long symbolic expressions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/88398/how-to-speed-up-an-optimization-with-very-long-symbolic-expressions)

The question may be clarified with a minimal non-working example.  The example is a bit silly, but it expresses the idea.

Suppose I have a list of expressions:

```
exampleTerms =  {(x - y)^2, x y, (x - y)^4};
exprList = Expand /@ RandomChoice[exampleTerms, 10] 
(*{x^4 - 4 x^3 y + 6 x^2 y^2 - 4 x y^3 + y^4,....}*)
```

Here is a list of terms that I'd like to precompute for insertion into a Function, or Compile:

```
vars =Union[Flatten[(List @@@ exprList) /. _?IntegerQ t_ :> t]]
(*{x y, x^3 y, x^2 y^2, x y^3}*)
```

Here is a list of rules pointing to intermediate variables:

```
assigments = 
 Thread[vars -> (Indexed[term, #] & /@ Range[Length[vars]])]
```

and here is what I want as the expr in Compile:

```
 expr = exprList /. assigments
    (*{x^2 -> Indexed[term, {1}], x^4 -> Indexed[term, {2}], 
 x y -> Indexed[term, {3}],...}*)

local = With[{termList = Indexed[term, #] & /@ Range[Length[vars]]},
  MapThread[HoldForm[#1 = #2] &, {termList, vars}]]
```

Here is something that looks like what I want:

```
tmpF = Function[{x, y},
  Evaluate[Block[Evaluate[local], Evaluate[expr]]]
  ]
```

But that fails because Block objects to the local variable assignment. (Also, the evaluates seem redundant, but it doesn't work if I remove them)
It also fails if I don't use Indexed:

```
tmpF = Function[{x, y},
  Evaluate[
   Block[Evaluate[local /. Indexed[term, i_] :> term[i]], 
    Evaluate[expr]]]
  ]
```

Or, which seems to be to be a total kludge by creating my own symbol names:

```
localAlt = With[{termList = 
    ToExpression["term" <> ToString[#]] & /@ Range[Length[vars]]},
  MapThread[HoldForm[#1 = #2] &, {termList, vars}]]

 exprAlt = 
     expr /. Indexed[p_, i_] :> ToExpression[ToString[p] <> ToString[i]]

tmpF = Function[{x, y},
  Evaluate[Block[localAlt, Evaluate[exprAlt]]]
  ]
```

Comment: One reason your `Block`examples don't work is because `Evaluate` will fully evaluate its arguments, including the assignments. This is course is not what you want for `Block`. What I usually do is to wrap my expressions in `Hold`, and then use a series of replacement to build uf the full expression, all inside the `Hold` wrapper. You have to make sure you are only relying on structural transformations, since your arguments (to `Block` in this case) should never be actually evaluated.

Comment: @LukasLang, Hmm, I've tried to implement your hint, but I've made no progress.  Do you mean something along the lines of this:  `Hold[
 exampleTerms =  {(x - y)^2, x y, (x - y)^4};
 exprList = Expand /@ RandomChoice[exampleTerms, 10];
 vars = Union[Flatten[(List @@@ exprList) /. _?IntegerQ t_ :> t]];
 assigments = 
  Thread[vars -> (Indexed[term, #] & /@ Range[Length[vars]])];
 expr = exprList /. assigments;
 tmpF = Function[{x, y}, 
   Evaluate[Block[Evaluate[local], Evaluate[expr]]]]
 
 ]; ReleaseHold[%]`

Comment: I initially tried to write an answer demonstrating the strategy I had in mind, but then I noticed that it can be done far simpler in this instance... (if you really want, I could add some demonstration to the answer, but it will be a lot messier in this case. Might be something for a second question with a more complicated goal)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way: Starting with your code, to define `vars` and `expr`, we can build the function like this:

```
With[
 {expr = expr, vars = vars},
 Function @@ Hold[{x, y}, Block[{term = vars}, expr]]
 ]
(* Function[{x, y}, 
 Block[{term = {x, x^2, x^4, y, x y, x^3 y, y^2, x^2 y^2, x y^3, 
     y^4}}, {Indexed[term, {3}] - 4 Indexed[term, {6}] + 
    6 Indexed[term, {8}] - 4 Indexed[term, {9}] + ...}]] *)
```

There are two things to note:

- I'm using [`With`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/With.html) to inject `expr` and `vars` into the function body without evaluating anything else.
- I'm using `Function@@Hold[...]` instead of `Function[...]` to ensure that `With` doesn't see that `{x,y}` are the arguments of `Function`. If it did, it would replace the names to prevent collisions with the `x` and `y` in `vars` and `expr`:

  ```
  With[
   {expr = expr, vars = vars},
   Function[{x, y}, Block[{term = vars}, expr]]
   ]
  (* Function[{x$, y$}, 
   Block[{term = {x, x^2, x^4, y, x y, x^3 y, y^2, x^2 y^2, x y^3, 
       y^4}}, {Indexed[term, {3}] - 4 Indexed[term, {6}] + 
      6 Indexed[term, {8}] - 4 Indexed[term, {9}] + ...}]] *)
  ```

That being said, you can simply use `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression `` to automatically perform the task for you:

```
Function[{x, y}, Evaluate@Experimental`OptimizeExpression[exprList]]
(* Function[{x, y}, 
 Block[{Compile`$13, Compile`$14, Compile`$15, Compile`$16, 
   Compile`$17, Compile`$18, Compile`$19, Compile`$20, Compile`$21, 
   Compile`$22, Compile`$23, Compile`$24}, Compile`$13 = x^4; 
  Compile`$14 = x^3; Compile`$15 = -4 Compile`$14 y; 
  Compile`$16 = x^2; Compile`$17 = y^2; 
  Compile`$18 = 6 Compile`$16 Compile`$17; Compile`$19 = y^3; 
  Compile`$20 = -4 x Compile`$19; Compile`$21 = y^4; 
  Compile`$22 = 
   Compile`$13 + Compile`$15 + Compile`$18 + Compile`$20 + 
    Compile`$21; Compile`$23 = -2 x y; 
  Compile`$24 = Compile`$16 + Compile`$23 + Compile`$17; {Compile`$22,
    Compile`$22, Compile`$24, Compile`$24, Compile`$22, Compile`$22, 
   Compile`$24, x y, Compile`$22, Compile`$24}]] *)
```

Comment: It is interesting that "Experimental`OptimizeExpression[exprList]" is different from what Compile[..., CompilationOptions -> {"ExpressionOptimization" -> True}] is doing under the hood.  The expressions are close, but "CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint" gives a result which is a little different. Puzzling why that effort appears to be roughly duplicated (I don't know how to make the back ticks not format like code in the above)

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks.