# Using Compiled Function in Implicit Region

Tags: compile, regions

I am looking for a way to speed up code and thus would like to use a compiled function in an `ImplicitRegion`.  Here is an example of a region that can be plotted normally, but fails when I try to use a compiled function. Is there a way to make this work?

```
RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[-x  y z > 0, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}]]
(*works*)

TEST=Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, -x  y z];
RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[TEST > 0, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}]]
(*fails*)
```

Comment: Have you tried `RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[TEST[x,y,z] > 0, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}]]`?

Comment: If you are unhappy with the warning message try this `cf = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, -x y z];
TEST[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := cf[x, y, z];
RegionPlot3D[
 ImplicitRegion[
  TEST[x, y, z] > 0, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}]]`

Comment: Doesn't `RegionPlot3D` compile its function anyway?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I'm not sure. I don't see anything about that on the documentation page, but you might be right

Comment: A lot of computationally intense functions do automatically compile in appropriate circumstances.  Check the timings `RegionPlot3D[ImplicitRegion[-x y z >  0, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}]] // RepeatedTiming` etc.  I found this original plot was slightly faster than blockwave's compiled version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works without any error messages:

```
TEST = Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}, {z, _Real}}, -x y z];

TESTfn[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ] := TEST[x, y, z];

RegionPlot3D[ImplicitRegion[TESTfn[x, y, z] > 0, {{x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5}}]]
```

The second function, `TESTfn`, is necessary to ensure you only pass numeric (and not symbolic) arguments to the compiled function, see for example [Using a compiled function inside NIntegrate gives "CompiledFunction::cfsa" message](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17993/using-a-compiled-function-inside-nintegrate-gives-compiledfunctioncfsa-messa).

[image]