# Numerical integration with purely numerical integrand

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to perform a numerical integral with an integrand that should not be manipulated with any symbolic preprocessing whatsoever. Consider the following simple test :

```
test[a_]:=If[NumericQ[a],a*a,Abort[] (*Meaning the parameter a is not numerical*)]
```

So if the parameter of `test` is numerical, this function should only return `a*a`. Now if I try to integrate this as follows:

```
NIntegrate[test[a],{a,-0.5,0.5},Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
```

this does not work (it will be aborted).
**Is there any way around this ? I.e. some option I haven't considered for NIntegrate ?**

Note that an easy way to fix this would be to use:

```
test[a_?NumericQ]:=If[NumericQ[a],a*a,Abort[]]
```

But **I want to avoid using** `?NumericQ`since this slows down your numerical integration by a lot...

Comment: [This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9971/) shows that `?NumericQ` *speeds up* integration a lot.  (In your case it may slow it down, but it does not always do so.)

Answer (score 2):

Including "SymbolicProcessing" -> False in the Method for NIntegrate gives equivalent timings with or without the NumericQ pattern test in the function's definition.

```
n = 1000; (* iterations in Do loops *)

test[a_] := a^2;

test2[a_?NumericQ] := a^2;

Do[NIntegrate[test[a], {a, -0.5, 0.5},
   Method -> {Automatic,
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}], {n}] //
 Timing
```

> {1.642638, Null}

```
Do[NIntegrate[test2[a], {a, -0.5, 0.5},
   Method -> {Automatic,
     "SymbolicProcessing" -> False}], {n}] //
 Timing
```

> {1.674284, Null}

Without "SymbolicProcessing" -> False, the NumericQ pattern test in the function's definition slightly improves the timing of NIntegrate in this case.

```
Do[NIntegrate[test[a], {a, -0.5, 0.5}], {n}] //
 Timing
```

> {5.708290, Null}

```
Do[NIntegrate[test2[a], {a, -0.5, 0.5}], {1000}] //
 Timing
```

> {4.512917, Null}

Comment: i suppose there should be some example where `NumericQ` hurts performance because `SymbolicProcessing` was able to do something useful.